# Hypothetical Grammer

Tags: will-would, will-shall

How are the following sentences different?

1. The sky is turning dark. It should be raining soon. (Why do we only use should and not shall. If we use shall be/shall it would be grammatically wrong?)
2. The sky is turning dark. It will be raining soon. (Can we say it would be raining soon? Or it will rain soon? If we use past tense here, how is it different from the present tense? Also, How is this statement different from (1)

Comment: Spelling: Gramm**ar**

Comment: In modern English, *shall* is mainly used with the 1st person pronouns I/we, and most commonly used in questions such as *Shall I/we go?*, etc, but is rarely used in the 2nd or 3rd person, except perhaps in older books. It's not wrong, but this usage is often viewed as very formal/old fashioned. I wouldn't use it except for questions with I/we. Otherwise, it's probably best avoided.